# Is it possible to have VUNIT run a test suite based on top level generics?

Tags: vunit

I am new to Vunit - but not testing. I currently have a setup where I have testbenches that use a lot of OSVVM where setup is provided via generics to the testbench, and I use either TCL or Pytest to run the test through a full test suite.

Having started looking into Vunit properly, I can see it might do what I'm after or at least allow me to move some of the test suit for some tests into the VHDL, but what I can't find is an example where part of the test case differences involve testing with different bus widths or sync/async clocks, for example.

Is there a way to do this via Vunit? if there is, is there an example I can look at? Or would you just expect to instantiate them all in the same Vunit testbench and run them in sequence?

My infrastructure is very OSVVM heavy, so I am not looking to change any of that - but I am looking for a runner to regress the testcases in GitLab. TCL doesn't cut it (mainly because ActiveHDL has a bug where it doesn't catch runtime exceptions properly in TCL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VUnit has a configuration concept (not to be confused with VHDL configurations) that allow you to do that, among other things. You can read about it [here](http://vunit.github.io/py/ui.html#configurations).

You can also look at the following [example](https://github.com/VUnit/vunit/tree/master/examples/vhdl/generate_tests).

I'm not sure if OSVVM heavy also implies using different **VHDL** configurations for different tests? If so, you should read [this](https://github.com/VUnit/vunit/issues/179)

**Update** based on comments:

Let's say we have a UUT with two generics, a `width` that can be 32/64/128 bits and a boolean `use_fifo`. Here's a dummy (but executable) representation of that UUT

```vhdl
entity uut is
  generic (
    width : positive;
    use_fifo : boolean);
end entity;

architecture a of uut is
begin
  do_stuff: process
  begin
    report "Width = " & to_string(width) & ", use_fifo = " & to_string(use_fifo);
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

Assume that we have a testbench and want to run that with all combinations of the generics. To do that we expose the UUT generics as generics to the VUnit testbench

```vhdl
library vunit_lib;
context vunit_lib.vunit_context;

entity tb_uut is
  generic (
    runner_cfg : string;
    width : positive;
    use_fifo : boolean);
end entity;

architecture tb of tb_uut is
begin
  main : process
  begin
    test_runner_setup(runner, runner_cfg);

    -- Do some testing

    test_runner_cleanup(runner);
  end process;

  uut_inst: entity work.uut
    generic map (
      width => width,
      use_fifo => use_fifo);
end architecture;
```

Now we can create VUnit configurations for the testbench that represent all generic combinations. This is done in the run script.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import product
from vunit import VUnit


prj = VUnit.from_argv()
root = Path(__file__).parent
lib = prj.add_library("lib")
lib.add_source_files(root / "*.vhd")

tb_uut = lib.test_bench("tb_uut")
for width, use_fifo in product([32, 64, 128], [False, True]):
    tb_uut.add_config(
        name=f"width={width}.use_fifo={use_fifo}",
        generics=dict(width=width, use_fifo=use_fifo),
    )

prj.main()
```

If we list the tests we will see all six combinations:

```
$ python run.py --list
lib.tb_uut.width=32.use_fifo=False
lib.tb_uut.width=32.use_fifo=True
lib.tb_uut.width=64.use_fifo=False
lib.tb_uut.width=64.use_fifo=True
lib.tb_uut.width=128.use_fifo=False
lib.tb_uut.width=128.use_fifo=True
Listed 6 tests
```

Comment: No, I avoid VHDL configurations. Currently I have a TCL script that can run the testbench in a given configuration. I have now started to use python to generate testcase configurations (in some cases) and use PyTest to run them all. Ideally, I just want something where I can go "Here are the test variables, now run all combinations of them".

Comment: An example might be: Run this UUT with a 32/64/128 bit axi interface, with or without a fifo instantiated. I dont think I could do that currently with VUNIT, where tests are defined in a top level VHDL wrapper.

Comment: No sure I fully understand but I updated the answer with an example to see if that is what you're looking for